# how to show error message if result in json is fail?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

In Ajax, the success part always executes. But if there is an error , I don't want to execute the normal; instead I want to show an error message.If the discount code is present then show/hide some div along with code and then redirect, else display the error message which we get in json response in the error div. How can i achieve this ?

Here is json response :

```
 {result: "fail", msg: "Code is not valid", redirect: 0}
```

controller :

```
 if($result == 'exp'){
  $discount_arr ['result'] = 'fail';
  $discount_arr['msg'] = 'Promotion code expired';
  $discount_arr['redirect'] = 0;
 }else{
  $discount_arr ['result'] = 'success';
  $discount_arr['msg'] = 'Valid Code';
  $discount_arr['url'] = base_url('cart');
  $discount_arr['redirect'] = 1;
 }
 echo json_encode($discount_arr);
```

HTML :

```
<div class="cart-secondary cart-discount-code">
        <label for="cart_Code">
        Discount Code </label>
        <input type="text" class="discount-code" name="cart_discountCode" id="cart_discountCode">
        <span class="error coupon-error"></span>
        <div class="confirm-coupon"></div>
        <button type="submit" value="addCoupon" name="addCoupon" id="add-coupon" onclick="checkStatus()">
        Apply </button>
```

Ajax:

```
 function checkStatus(){
var discount_code = $(".cart-secondary .cart-discount-code .discount-code").val();

$.ajax(
{
    url     : "<?php echo base_url('cart/validate/'); ?>",
    type    : "POST",
    data    : {discount_code: discount_code} ,
    cache     : false,
    dataType:'json',
    statusCode: {
        404: function() {
          alert( "page not found" );
        }
    },
    success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
    {
        if(textStatus == 'success'){
                $('input[name=cart_discountCode]').val(discount_code);
                $('.cart-secondary .cart-discount-code-show span').html(discount_code);
                $(".cart-discount-code").fadeOut();
                $(".cart-discount-code-show").fadeIn();
                if(data.redirect){
                    window.location.reload();
                }

        }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //if fails
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
}
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use an `else` for your `if` comparison.
**update:** you are accessing the wrong variable of your success-callback. you are not interested in the `textStatus`, you want to read the data you are returning by yourself. the returned json object is saved in the `data` variable:

```
if(data.result == 'success'){
    /* ... */

}else{
    $(".error").text(data.msg);
}
```

Comment: Even if my result is fail,it replaces the div and all which should happen only if result is success @low_rents

Comment: @Snehal glad that i could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can access those information in `data` variable of success callback of the AJAX function.

Use it like this,

```
success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
    {
        if(data.result != 'fail'){
                $('input[name=cart_discountCode]').val(discount_code);
                $('.cart-secondary .cart-discount-code-show span').html(discount_code);
                $(".cart-discount-code").fadeOut();
                $(".cart-discount-code-show").fadeIn();
                if(data.redirect){
                    window.location.reload();
                }

        } else {
           alert(redirect.message);
           if(data.redirect==1) {
                // redirect here..
           }
        }
    }
```

So access those data using,

```
data.message
data.redirect
data.result
```

It's normally as you access property of any JavaScript object.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting 
{result: "fail", msg: "Code is not valid", redirect: 0} in success block,

then do this

```
success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
    {
        if(data.result !== 'fail' && textStatus == 'success'){
                $('input[name=cart_discountCode]').val(discount_code);
                $('.cart-secondary .cart-discount-code-show span').html(discount_code);
                $(".cart-discount-code").fadeOut();
                $(".cart-discount-code-show").fadeIn();
                if(data.redirect){
                    window.location.reload();
                }

        }
    },
```